# How can I get descreption text from html string?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parse HTML iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6396901/parse-html-iphone)

I am new in iPhone development
I want text after  tag and before

can anyone suggest

Printing description of tenpDesc:

```
<p><a href="http://news.yahoo.com/blogs/lookout/isaac-hurricane-163319596.html"><img src="http://l1.yimg.com/bt/api/res/1.2/Vjy6kqzuLBWRutEELYQRoQ--/YXBwaWQ9eW5ld3M7Zmk9ZmlsbDtoPTg2O3E9ODU7dz0xMzA-/http://media.zenfs.com/en_us/News/Reuters/2012-08-28T142918Z_1781079790_GM1E88S1QC101_RTRMADP_3_STORM-ISAAC.JPG" width="130" height="86" alt="New Orleans resident Whipple watches waves crash on the shore of Lake Pontchartrain as Tropical Storm Isaac approaches New Orleans" align="left" title="New Orleans resident Whipple watches waves crash on the shore of Lake Pontchartrain as Tropical Storm Isaac approaches New Orleans" border="0" /></a>Tropical Storm Isaac is now Hurricane Isaac. The slow-moving storm, with maximum sustained winds of 75 mph, achieved hurricane status at approximately 12:20 p.m. ET on Tuesday, the National Hurricane Center said: ...RECONNAISSANCE DATA INDICATE ISAAC FINALLY ACHIEVES HURRICANE STATUS...REPORTS FROM AN AIR FORCE RESERVE HURRICANE HUNTER AIRCRAFT INDICATE THAT MAXIMUM WINDS ASSOCIATED WITH ISAAC HAVE [...]</p><br clear="all"/>
```

Thanks

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: this might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4217820/convert-html-to-nsattributedstring-in-ios I'd go with the NSScanner, as often html sites arent valid xml.

Answer (score -2):

This requires parsing and is not native in Objective-C.  You must program or find a 3rd party parser (which I do not know of any personally).

Comment: this is wrong. cocoa offers [xml-parser](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and [NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html).